# Yarn UI Logs are unavailable because Application Timeline Service seems unhealthy

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

Recently, we've installed Cloudera 7.
In a new Yarn UI, I can't see logs of an application.

[scrrenshot of yarnUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7NKG.png)

Error in the UI:
**Logs are unavailable because Application Timeline Service seems unhealthy.**

After starting new timelineServer with this command
**`yarn --daemon start timelinereader`**
I still can't see logs.

In a browser console, I can see Cross-origin errors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://<host1>:8188/ws/v2/timeline/health?_=1590476843427' 
from origin 'http://<host2>:8088' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

vendor.js:572 GET http://<host1>:8188/ws/v2/timeline/health?_=1590476843427 net::ERR_FAILED
```

After configuring Cross-origin support using this link:
https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.0.2/yarn-security/topics/yarn-configure-cross-origin-support-for-yarn.html
the error is still present.